# Setting dependencies in Visual Studio for a p/invoke-called library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, pinvoke

We tried to create a C++/CLI project around a native C++ DLL that uses boost, but we had troubles compiling boost with /cli (it crashed on Windows 7 too).

So we decided to go the P/Invoke way and to "loadlibrary" the native DLL from a .Net wrapper component.

We are having a hard time making sure that Visual Studio can compile the native DLL and refresh the .Net wrapper correctly.

We have added the native .dll as a linked file in the wrapper .Net project folder, but when Visual Studio compiles the native .dll, the .Net wrapper project still sees an old version of the native .dll.

If we try to add a dependency and we point to the .dll, Visual Studio says it cannot add the dependency because it is neither a .net component nor a COM one.
If we add a project dependency it fails for the same reason.

What is the best way to tell Visual Studio to refresh the native .dll and have the P/Invoke wrapper see a fresh copy of it (so we can debug our changes?)

Thanks -

Comment: When you make changes to the unmanaged code, rebuild it

Comment: Thanks David - I did add a manual dependency between projects in the solution, but that did not help.

Comment: I don't think you can expect to get the tool to recognise this dependency. Do as I said. When you change the unmanaged code, recompile the managed code. If you recompile the DLL and the consumer doesn't pick it up, you are doing something wrong. Sounds like you aren't clear as to where the files should live. I think you haven't diagnosed the problem correctly yet.